# Request: Make "fireworks" and "adobe-fireworks" synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Please make [fireworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fireworks) and [adobe-fireworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-fireworks) synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the 10 posts with "fireworks" they have now been converted over to "adobe-fireworks" and the tag synonym created for it.